# can xsd definition of type reference the xml file itself?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am trying to describe a set of java classes using XML. I need to have an xsd document as robost as possible, so it saves me headaches later on. 
Suppose I have a class node inside which I have a set or properties. Each property have a type attribute, the value of this attribute could be a class name in the xml document, or a set of primitive names like "integer" "float" etc.

Can this scenario be defined in a xsd document?

thanks a bunch.

Comment: In general, yes it can. Do you need some further explanations? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I have specific need that cannot be addressed with current frameworks. Amont them is the fact that the data is coming in in multiple files. Anyhow that is not the point, the point is how can I address this issue in XSD, that is the real question. I want xsd to be as restrictive as possible.

Comment: I've recently written part of a framework that generates metadata descriptors in XML for Java classes. The XML documents are created by constructing a bean tree in an annotation processor, then marshalling via JAXB. When the descriptors are needed at runtime, they're unmarshalled from XML back to the beans, again using JAXB. While it sounds simple, I can assure you that a good understanding of W3C XML Schema and Java inheritance are required to pull this off. Your self-accepted answer leads me to believe you should first study XML Schema thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with ref/refid and key in the xsd.

Comment: This answer is as incomprehensible as the question. It goes no clue as to the actual problem that you were trying to solve, nor how using references will help you. SO would be better off if you simply deleted the question.